# SpriteKit scene becomes unresponsive

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, game-development

I have two SpriteKit scenes in my game. 
a menu scene and a More scene defined below

```
var scene0:SKScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Store")!
var scene1:SKScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Menu")!
```

in my menu scene I have a button called Store that takes user to the Store scene. when more is tapped the following code is executed

```
            self?.view?.presentScene(scene0, transition:self!.fadeTrans)
```

in storeScene I have a back button that takes the user back to the menu
the back button has the following code

```
self?.view?.presentScene(scene1, transition:self!.fadeTrans)
```

problem is that when I go from store to menu the game becomes unresponsive
.

I have attached a gif[image: error gif] to demonstrate

Comment: Did you run the game on a device or only on a simulator?

Comment: I’ve tried it om both. It freezes even if its a real device

Comment: I noticed you are getting terrible frame-rates. Run the simulator on iPhone SE or another simulator with a smaller screen-size. Its unrelated but it might help you with frame-rate.

Comment: @E.Huckabee frame rate is not an issue. I had illustrator running in the background. But the freezing scene issue is persistent even when no other apps are running and even when I run the game on a real device

Comment: If you know some dev who can help me with this then please send them a link to this. I’ve been scratching my hear for two days :(